# StripeInvalidRequestError: You can only create new accounts if you've signed up for Connect

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

When trying to test Stripe Connect Api, I get the following error:

> 'StripeInvalidRequestError: You can only create new accounts if you've
> signed up for Connect'

I have signed up for an account and I use my personal Secret Key so i don't know why its not letting me test this feature. Below is the code for the post request.

```
router.post('/api/post/create-stripe-account', async (req,res) => {
    
        const data = req.body;
        try{
            var account = await stripe.accounts.create({
                country: 'US',
                type: 'custom',
                requested_capabilities: ['card_payments', 'transfers'],
            });
    
            res.json(account)
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
        
    
    })
```

Link to documentation that I followed: [Using Connect with Custom Accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/custom-accounts)

Any thoughts why stripe doesn't think I have signed up? I have used this secret key successfully with sending payments by card but stripe connect doesn't seem to like it. Thanks!

Comment: Here is how I required stripe at the top of the file `const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);`. The .env file is using my `sk_test_` secret key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to create new accounts in test mode using your test API key (starting with `sk_test_`).  Can you confirm that's the key you're using on your server?

The error you're getting usually indicates your Connect platform application is not complete and you're trying to create an account in live mode (using your `sk_live_` key).  In order to create accounts in live mode you need to complete [your platform profile in the Stripe Dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/connect/accounts/overview).

Comment: Yes sir. This is the beginning of my .env file  -->    `STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = sk_test_ `

Comment: as Justin said you need to complete your profile - https://dashboard.stripe.com/connect/accounts/overview before creating custom accounts

Comment: Do you have Connect enabled in test mode here? https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/connect/accounts/overview  Does anything seem amiss in your Connect settings here? https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/settings/applications

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. This solved my problem. I had to accept the terms and services to use connect even though I was using a test secret key. Thank you!

Comment: Is it mandatory to activate the account? What if I belong to a country that doesn't support stripe. Is there any free developer or sandbox account?

Comment: @Tina It depends on your specific use case.  For the specific question above you don't need to activate the platform account to create Custom accounts in test mode, but your situation may be different.  I recommend contacting Stripe Support to get help for your specific scenario: https://support.stripe.com/contact

Comment: Thanks, contacted them and found that the connect and few other functionalities aren't available from accounts that aren't activated. So, as I am a developer from stripe unsupported countries I won't be able to use that even in test mode :(  Thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 1):

I followed these steps from stripe docs and it works.

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue based on [Justin Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1076562)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62824215/stripeinvalidrequesterror-you-can-only-create-new-accounts-if-youve-signed-up/72177610#comment111099022_62824334)

> Do you have Connect enabled in test mode here? dashboard.stripe.com/test/connect/accounts/overview Does anything seem amiss in your Connect settings here? dashboard.stripe.com/test/settings/applications –
> Justin Michael
> Jul 9, 2020 at 23:31

Click on get started only then you can get access to create function of stripe.

[image]